# How did the concept of quartile and Inter-quartile Range came into existence?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

What is the sequence of historical events that led to the creation of the concept of quartile and Inter-quartile Range? And while calculating IQR, why do we consider the 75th percentile as the upper quartile and the 25th percentile as the lower quartile, and why not the 90th percentile as the upper quartile and the 10th percentile as the lower quartile?

Comment: Quartile is related to dividing the range into four parts. The aim is to exclude outliers. The first 10% is the first decile and the last 10% is the tenth decile. I am sure you will get more detail on this, but hope this comment helps a little.

Comment: The words *quartile* and *interquartile range* were [first used](https://web.universiteitleiden.nl/fsw/verduin/stathist/1stword.htm) by Francis Galton in the late 19th century.  The words *decile* and *percentile*  too, though *quintile* came later .

Comment: In addition to quartile being based on quarter , the IQR covers 50% of the Central Cases , thus it is representative of the whole DataSet.